# SharePoint 2013; SharePoint 2010 workflows do not update when published using SharePoint Designer

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Updated SharePoint 2010 workflows do not work until iisreset.

I am using:

- SharePoint 2013 with CU's updated through May 2015
- SharePoint Designer 2013 32bit

Procedure:

1. Create a new list with two columns Title (default), NewText (single line text )
2. Create a SharePoint 2010 list workflow using SPD2013. The workflow is set to run manually only. Its only action is to put text into the NewText field when it runs.
3. Create a list item
4. Run the workflow manually - It works fine
5. Edit the workflow in SPD2013 to simply put different text in the NewText field. e.g. initially the text was "FirstTry" changed to "SecondTry"
6. Check for Errors (none of course)
7. Publish - no errors
8. I look at the workflows for the list and see that the original workflow was replaced as expected. (The new workflow is listed with the original workflow listed with (Previous Version . . . .) after the name.
9. Run the workflow on the item - the text DOES NOT change.
10. Create a new item
11. Run the workflow - the text is set to "FirstTry" NOT "SecondTry"
12. Recheck the workflow in SPD, republish etc. no change
13. Do an iisreset - now the workflow sets the text to "SecondTry" as desired. further changes continue to have the problem as described above.

I have tried this on multiple site collections, list, different fields etc

I have tried the suggestions from others on this. The most common is clear %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache.  This does not work for me with no change is symptoms.

Other suggestion was to create the WF as a SharePoint 2013 workflow.  Although this seems to work OK (I actually have a different problem with this) it is not a final answer because there are times we need to use SP2010 workflows.  An example is that SP2013 will only use SP2010 workflows as a workflow approval action. Also SP2013 workflows do not provide a start approval process AND all of the OOTB workflows are based on the SP2010 workflows.

We really need to be able to update the SP2010 workflows - obviously iisreset is not a solution.

I am pulling my hair out on this one.  Help!!  Please!!

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from TechNet Community  it appears to work.

I recommend to enable versioning in workflows list and then check if the issue still occurs.
Open SharePoint Designer > click All Files > right click Workflows under All Files tab and select Properties > click Administration Web Page button in the menu > click Versioning Settings in the browser.

Here is a similar thread for your reference:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a63a1894-6b1d-420a-95dd-b6c546eab34d/updates-made-to-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow-do-not-show-up-on-the-server?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious